# × TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') react js

Tags: reactjs

i am not able to display country name,image and rating can anyone explain me why this is happening [https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=avengers] it is the API link.all other data are displaying but these 3 are not working and throwing error.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {
  const url = 'https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=avengers'

  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((json) => setData(json.data))
  }, [])

  const renderTable = () => {
    return data.map((user) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{user.show.name}</td>
          <td>{user.show.language}</td>
          <td>{user.show.genres}</td>
          <td>{user.show.runtime}</td>
          <td>{user.show.premiered}</td>
          <td>{user.show.rating}</td>
          <td>{user.show.country.name}</td>
          <td>{user.image.medium}</td>


        </tr>
      )
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 id="title">API Table</h1>
      <table id="users">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>language</th>
            <th>genres</th>
            <th>runtime</th>
            <th>premiered</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>country name</th>
            <th>image</th>



          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{renderTable()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those fields are missing from the API data for some of the items. You should guard against that eventuality by using them as:

```
<td>{user?.show?.country?.name}</td>
<td>{user?.image?.medium}</td>
```

EDIT:
I've also noticed some of the fields were just wrong. Maybe try the following for the last 3 lines:

```
<td>{user?.show?.rating?.average}</td> 
<td>{user?.show?.country?.name}</td>
<td>{user?.show?.image?.medium}</td>
```

Comment: still not getting image and country name but rating is now being displayed

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhanananthu `user?.show?.network?.country` might fix the country name. 
For the item with ID 49336 returned by the API call, images are not available at all.

Comment: And you can always use a placeholder image for that, something like `user?.show?.image?.medium ?? 'https://url.for.placeholder.image'` .

Comment: i am not getting country name

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhanananthu Again, there's missing data on the API. You need to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your code:

1. You should use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when destructuring nested values
2. You should add a key for every item returned through map
3. You are destructuring `rating` incorrectly. It should be `user?.show?.rating?.average` instead of `user.show.rating` which is an object.

Update code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const url = "https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=avengers";

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((json) => setData(json.data));
  }, []);

  const renderTable = () => {
    return data.map((user, i) => {
     return (
     <tr key={i}>
      <td>{user.show?.name}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.language}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.genres}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.runtime}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.premiered}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.rating?.average}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.network?.country?.name}</td>
      <td>
        <img src={user?.show?.image?.medium} alt="poster" />
      </td>
    </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 id="title">API Table</h1>
      <table id="users">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>language</th>
            <th>genres</th>
            <th>runtime</th>
            <th>premiered</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>country name</th>
            <th>image</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{renderTable()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: still not getting image and countryname

Comment: rating is being showed now

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhanananthu I've updated the answer. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the country name is inside of the network object. In this case i think should be: **user.show.network.country.name** and for the image: **user.show.image.medium**
[json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N573p.png)

Comment: nop is getting error